# How to reinstall a package using 'apt-get'?

Tags: debian, aptitude, debian-lenny

It seems that my `aptitude` is somehow broken:

```
sudo aptitude update
0% [Working]Segmentation fault

dmesg
[223282.616599] aptitude[30972]: segfault at 67707f ip 7f954dcfae5d sp 7ffff5a5f950 error 4 in libapt-pkg-libc6.7-6.so.4.6.0[7f954dca5000+bd000]
```

So I would like to reinstall `aptitude` by using `apt-get`.

Unfortunately it seems `apt-get` doesn't have a reinstall option.

How could I get `aptitude` to work again?

It's possible that I found the root cause for aptitude's segfault. Here is how I can reproduce it:

1. 'ssh' remote login into the Debian machine via Cygwin's rxvt terminal (from a Windows 7 64-bit German edition).
2. Enlarge the rxvt window so that it spans across two monitors (yes, I have two monitors)
3. Run `aptitude update`. Note: when I resize the rxvt terminal to normal then I don't have these segmentation faults!

Comment: These are great two separate questions. One is how to reinstall a package, which is in the title and which is answered. The other one is, how to deal with aptitude crash on a too wide terminal.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

```
$ man apt-get | grep reinsta -A2
       --reinstall
           Re-Install packages that are already installed and at the newest
           version. Configuration Item: APT::Get::ReInstall.
```

So, to use it to reinstall `aptitude` use:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall aptitude
```

Comment: what's that `-A5` you are grepping ?

Comment: man grep | grep -- "-A"

Comment: What's that `--` you're grepping?

Comment: `man getopt`, look under `PARSING`

Comment: `-A5` shows the matched line plus the following 5 lines. `--` stops parsing of options, thus interpreting anything that comes after as positional arguments, avoiding having to escape the dash in the  expression `-A` which would otherwise be interpreted as an option to grep itself.

Comment: @jjmontes So technically quotes around  `"-A"` are not necesary: `man grep | grep -- -A`

Comment: @DimitryK Yes, `grep -- "-A"` is *exactly* the same thing as `grep -- -A`. The quotes are interpreted *by the shell* and `grep` always sees the second parameter as `-A`. And obviously the `--` is required before that to make sure it's interpreted as query instead of flag `-A`. (Windows programmers will have different experience because `cmd` has  much less smarts than UNIX shell.)

Answer (score 160):

You can reinstall a package with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename`.
This completely removes the package (but not the packages that depend on it), then reinstalls the package.

This can be convenient when the package has many reverse dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for being the only correct, complete, non-snarky answer.

Comment: @Cerin: I wouldn't call the other answers overly snarky: even the "read the man page" one actually gave the answer as well as how to find it.

Comment: @DavidSpillett, I strongly disagree. The man pages are usually very poorly written and are very unfriendly to newbies. For example, the paragraph on the "--reinstall" option doesn't mention that you have to use it with the "install" argument. A newbie might rightfully ask "why do I have to tell it to install AND reinstall?" An answer telling someone to RTFM is the worst kind of answer and it pains me to see it with the most votes, especially when a complete and actually helpful answer is near the bottom.

Comment: You can use `apt` instead `apt-get` too: `sudo apt install --reinstall packagename`

Answer (score 35):

Sometimes you need to restore config files too! not just reinstall.

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xxxx`

Reinstall the application, keeps the config files.

This could be helpful, but sometimes you need to start fresh, so what I use is this:

```
sudo dpkg -r xxxx //to remove that xxxx package
sudo dpkg -P xxxx //to purge all related files
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install xxxx
```

Comment: And if you need to restore config files only, in some cases (if they are managed by ucf) you should use `UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=1 apt-get --reinstall install [pkgname]`.

Comment: This answer deserves a BIG upvote.This is what you need when you want to "fully reinstall" a package. E.g. a simple --reinstall of vsftpd doesn't re-create the config file, even if the file doesn't exist anymore. A "Remove+Purge+(Re)install" does the job instead.

Answer (score 14):

You should be safe to remove aptitude and reinstall, as that won't affect the other apt utilities. So: `apt-get remove aptitude` followed by `apt-get install aptitude`, or if that still fails try `apt-get purge aptitude` followed by `apt-get install aptitude`.

Before doing either of the above, I recommend a full file-system and bad-block check in case there is a problem there that caused the problem (depending on the problem, if there is one, further activity could make things worse). Also, make sure you review what will be removed in the remove/purge step before letting it proceed (it should pause to ask for permission if anything extra is changed as a result of removing that one package), to double check my thought that this is safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `apt-get remove` followed by `apt-get install` did the trick!

Comment: It's a long time ago that I did things like `a full filesystem check` or similar. Could you please give me a short hint howto do that?

Comment: `fsck -f <block_device>` such as `fsck /dev/sda1`. The filesystem will need to be unmounted or mounted read-only at the time so as this is likely to be your root filesystem you should reboot into single-user-mode or boot from something else like a live cd.

Comment: @David: Is there a way to force a `filesystem check on next reboot` ?

Comment: You can use `tune2fs` to mark the filesystem as having been mounted more times than its set limit, that should force a check next boot. Assuming the filesystem is ext2/3/4: `tune2fs -C 99 <device>`, or in case you have mount count based checking turned off, turn it on at the same time with something like `tune2fs -c 17 -C 99 <device>`.

Comment: touch /forcefsck;reboot

Answer (score 3):

If you want a reinstall with complete config wipe:
sudo apt remove --purge package
sudo apt install package

That's like you never had installed the package before. I am doing this often with motion and such things.

Comment: The problem with that technique is that it deletes all your changes to the settings under `/etc/...` which may not be what you want...

Comment: In other cases it can be exactly what you want. Sometimes you just want to get back original config or just do a cleanup

Comment: Absolutely. Actually, when I test my new packages I do that a lot until I'm satisfied with the installation process. So it can be very useful. On the other hand, it can be a gotcha if you don't first backup your settings with some specific data which you don't have anywhere else (you probably can come up with it again, but it can be time consuming).